# Mosfets vs. Buckpucks in driving high power leds

Tags: mosfet

I searched for an answer but I'm so unfamiliar with some of the terms used in electrical engineering that if there was an appropriate answer I didn't recognize it.

I am running 4 high powered leds and was getting ready to buy 4 buckpuck, which would cost me about 50 bucks. I get conflicting views from various sources about whether buckpucks are necessary, so I thought I would ask you guys if mosfets are a viable option for obvious monetary reasons.

I need to address the leds individually (in parallel) and they need to be dimmed via a microcontroler using pwm. They run at 1000mah and I was told that that must be a constant current, thus the need for buckpucks.

Can mosfets work? And if so, how do I do it and what should I be aware of?

Comment: 1000 mA or 1000 mAh?  (one is current, the other is a common measure of battery capacity)

Comment: Buckpuck comes with MOSFET pre-installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer your question the safest and best way to drive an LED would be in constant current mode, instead of using MOSFETs(like the buck puck does it)a quick good search for 1A constant current driver showed up a bunch of dedicated ICs for driving LEDs at 1000mA(like this one http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/CAT4101-D.PDF). they're cheap, about ~US$ 3  in single piece qty on digikey. they have an ENABLE/PWM line with which you can DIM or enable/disable each individual LED(you will need one chip per LED). Also post the specs for the LEDs that you plan to use, to make it easy for people to help you! Good luck! [image]

Answer (score 1):

BuckPucks are a branded retail product. Internal to the BuckPuck is some proprietary current-regulated circuit, which undoubtedly contains resistors, capacitors, transistors (MOSFETs and/or BJTs), diodes, and probably many other components and ICs.

MOSFETs are a type of transistor and are a basic component of electronic circuits. They do nothing by themselves and require a good understanding of how they work to successfully incorporate them into a design.

Here's an analogy: A BuckPuck is like buying a Honda Civic. It's a fully functional system made up of many many parts. A MOSFET is like a piston in the engine. It's just one component of a much bigger system.

You'll definitely want to use a constant-current regulator to drive your LEDs. But there are literally thousands of ways to design regulators, many of which use MOSFETs. Some designs are more robust or cheaper or more flexible or use less parts or use more parts. There's no one way to design anything in electronics.

It sounds like you stand at a crossroads. You can choose to drop 50 bucks on some BuckPucks (or any number of other pre-packaged LED drivers on the market). Or you can learn about electronics design and figure out how to make your own. The former is quick, but you're forever limited to what other people have already designed. The latter is long, grueling, but incredibly rewarding.

Comment: Thanks. I will inevitably take the long road eventually, but I'm a student so my electronics hobby gets little of my time. I'm a Computer Science major just dabbling right now. I appreciate the help.